# SQL Server : daily beginning inventory and ending inventory report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following data

[image]

I would like to compute for the beginning and ending inventory. The formula is Beginning Inventory + Purchases = Ending Inventory.  The results should be this:

[image]

Is it possible using a T-SQL query?

Comment: Search for "running sum" on SQL. You can do this with either windowed functions (rolling sums) or correlated subqueries with totals. Lots of examples here in StackOverflow.

Comment: any sample syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Set up sample data as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #Inventory (
ReportingDate date NOT NULL,
Purchases int NOT NULL
);
GO
INSERT INTO #Inventory (ReportingDate,Purchases)
VALUES 
    ('20181101',77000),
    ('20181102',100000),
    ('20181108',0),
    ('20181109',0),
    ('20181201',164000),
    ('20181208',0),
    ('20181215',0);
GO
```

Try the following for SQL Server 2008 and earlier:

```
WITH Pre2012Inv AS (
    SELECT      *,
                (SELECT SUM(Purchases) FROM #Inventory iv WHERE iv.ReportingDate <= i.ReportingDate) AS EndingInventory,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ReportingDate ASC) AS RowNum
    FROM        #Inventory i
)
SELECT          p.ReportingDate,
                ISNULL(p1.EndingInventory,0) AS BeginningInventory,
                p.Purchases,
                p.EndingInventory
FROM            Pre2012Inv p
    LEFT JOIN   Pre2012Inv p1 ON p1.RowNum = p.RowNum-1;
```

Try the following for SQL Server 2012 and later:

```
WITH Inv AS (
    SELECT      *,
                SUM(Purchases) OVER (ORDER BY ReportingDate ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)   AS EndingInventory
    FROM        #Inventory
)
SELECT          ReportingDate,
                LAG(EndingInventory,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY ReportingDate ASC)                  AS BeginningInventory,
                Purchases,
                EndingInventory
FROM            Inv;
```